# How do you say idiomatically that a clock on the wall is not showing the correct time?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, idiomatic-language

A native Anglophone lady is showing around her house on TV. When they walk into a room, there is a big clock on the wall, and she points at the clock and says:

**"That is not the time."**

I understand that the clock has run out of the battery (she also says this), so the clock is not showing the correct time.

However, I would never be able to make up such a sentence as a non-native speaker. I would probably say "**"The clock is not correct."**.

So, I searched for the sentence on google, whether it is common to mean the clock is not working, but I could not find any. So, I am kind of surprised.

Also, the sentence **"That is not the time"** reminds me a meaning such as "It is not the time to play/to eat/to drink/to sleep etc" which is used to warn someone not to do whatever it is they are doing at the wrong time or place.

So, is the sentence **"That is not the time"** an idiomatic way of saying that a clock is not showing the correct time?

[Here is the link.](https://youtu.be/8m6Y0PaBNx8?t=190) She says the sentence at on 3:10

Comment: If you *know* the clock, you'd probably say *That clock's **ten minutes fast / an hour slow.*** If you've no idea how *much* it's wrong by, you might say *That clock's **wrong*** (or maybe ***...doesn't work*** if you've been aware of it for long enough to notice that the hands aren't moving at all). Feasibly *That clock's not showing the right time*, but that's a bit "wordy". If it's known that the battery has run down, maybe *That clock has stopped*. Compare *My watch has stopped (because I didn't wind it up)*.

Comment: "That is not the time" doesn't sound like what I would say as a native speaker.  I'd probably say "That clock's wrong", like FumbleFingers, or maybe "That's clock's off."  She might have meant something like "That (time that is indicated on the clock) is not the (real) time", though.

Comment: I'm a native New Yorker (City); I'd think nothing of saying - or hearing - "That's not the time" when referring to a clock that's wrong. I'd think it only a little odd to hear "That is not the time" simply because it's unusual to not hear the "is" contracted with the "That" - or, alternatively, with the "not" ("That isn't the time").

Comment: If it has "run out of battery" (a flat battery), **the clock has stopped**.

Comment: "The clock is not correct" isn't wrong but "The clock's not right" is more colloquial. There are, as other people indicate, lots of ways of saying this.

Comment: Regarding the wording of your question:  By **a native lady**, do you mean someone whose native language is English. Otherwise, the description is puzzling.  And **showing around her house** needs an object after **showing**. She has to be showing someone around the house.  And I'm not clear by what you mean by saying **on TV**.  Are you watching a video on TV?

Comment: @RonaldSole, Yes I mean someone whose native language is English. And yes, she is showing the TV crew around the house. She is a famous panelist on Loose Women on ITV. Here is the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8m6Y0PaBNx8    She says it on 3:10

Comment: But she *doesn't* say **That is not the time.** She says **That Isn't the time**, with clear emphasis on the contracted word ***isn't***, which is significantly different. She's not really *interested* in the clock itself (even though it's a very unusual *huge* wall clock) - she's only interested in pointing out that the ***time*** displayed isn't the same as her ***current time of speaking***. So given that relatively unusual context, I think it's a pointless example to be asking whether what she says is "idiomatic". It's unusual, but so is the situation.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, So, do you mean "is not" and "isn't" are not the same thing in this sentence? At school, this is one of the first things that we learners are taught: "isn't=is not / aren't=are not". So, you say an emphasis on "isn't" changes the meaning. Does this apply to other similar sentences if I emphasize the "ISN'T". For exampe would there be any difference between the two if I said "ISN'T" with an emphasis? "This IS NOT a pencil". AND "This ISN'T a pencil?"

Comment: Surely you can see that the context is unusual. You're asking *What would a person normally say in this situation?*, but the situation you've found is just "odd". I have the feeling the woman doesn't particularly want to mention that huge overpowering wall clock behind her, but because it's so obviously *not* showing the correct time, she has to say *something*. Then since it *has* been mentioned, she thinks she has to "justify" the situation by bringing up the battery.

Comment: @yunus "is not" and "isn't" mean the same thing, but native speakers don't necessarily _use_ them interchangeably. Word choice can play a large role in whether something is idiomatic English or not. -- In this particular case, I'd say that "is not" comes off a bit formal, and conflicts with the ellipsis in the statement "That (time that is indicated on the clock) is not the (real) time". The conversational omissions move it more into a casual register, which would idiomatically use the contraction instead. (See Jeff Zeitlin comment.)

Comment: It's not idiomatic… it's a simple fact, even though in the given example that might not be obvious.

Can you say why you wouldn't be able to make up such a sentence or why you would prolly say 'The clock is not correct' rather than 'That is not the time"?

Strictly, no-one would use either wording; only instead 'The clock is wrong.'

FYI, 'the clock has run out of the battery' is understandable, but wrong.

So are 'the clock has run out of battery' and 'the battery of the clock has run out'.

You needed 'the clock battery has run out' - not even 'the clock's battery…'

Comment: I feel so old reading all the comments. For a considerable portion of my life, most ordinary clocks and watches were powered mechanically, usually by a spring or slowly falling weight. Not a battery in sight. You had to wind the spring or raise the weight periodically, and if they lost or gained time you needed to 'regulate' them or get a watch- or clock-maker to do it. My grandparents were very proud that their grandfather clock's chimes each day at 6 PM coincided with the beeps of the BBC radio 'time signal'.

Comment: Importantly, there are several ways for a clock to be wrong. It could be stopped completely; it could be running at the right pace, but indicate completely the wrong time; it could be running at the right pace, but be slightly early or late by a few minutes; it could be running slightly too fast or too slow; etc. There is more than one way to say that the clock is wrong, depending on how specific you want to be about how wrong it is.

Comment: @Mazura - _Frequency Instability Problems in North American Interconnections_ National Energy Technology Laboratory (US Dept of Energy) [paper here](https://netl.doe.gov/sites/default/files/Smartgrid/TransmissionFreqProb.pdf). This is absolutely typical of grids in developed countries.

Comment: "the Eastern Interconnection load traditionally consists of more
rotating industrial machines than the other interconnections and consequently has better frequency response characteristics." - OK, I recant "the US" and resubmit the 'Eastern Interconnection'. Downtown Chicago has been lit for 20y straight and counting.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

We would be more likely to say 'That's not the right time', or 'that clock is wrong'. If the clock is running, but the time shown is behind the correct time, we can say 'that clock is slow', and if the time shown is ahead of the correct time, we can say 'that clock is fast'.

Comment: Agreed.  I might also say "that's not the correct time", or "that's not the actual time".  The point here is that there would usually be some word to emphasize that it is actually _incorrect_ instead of simply not desired/appropriate, etc.

Comment: "That clock is wrong" works in any case. But "That's not the right time" would be more idiomatic to be said by someone realising the clock is wrong for the first time, rather than by someone who already knows the clock is wrong. This is because a clock that's wrong will basically always show the wrong time, so focusing on the current time being wrong is overly specific.

Comment: Possibly of note, saying a clock is fast or slow is partly ambiguous. It could either mean that it is ahead or behind the correct time, or that it is actually running/ticking faster or slower than it should be, with the second meaning being the most common cause of the first meaning (hence this usage of ‘fast’ and ‘slow’).

Comment: @AustinHemmelgarn - agreed but I think that at least from my experience starting before digital or electronic clocks were common, saying 'that clock is slow/fast' upon first noting a discrepancy in the time shown by a newly-seen clock generally means the first. The clock could be running at the right rate but merely set wrong.

Comment: @NotThatGuy - 'a clock that's wrong will basically always show the wrong time' - not always. A clock that is stopped is right once every 12 hours and one that gains or loses 1 minute every day will be right every 720 days.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey is right. With modern clocks (digital or with hands) "fast" seems to always mean "ahead of the real time". If it started at the right time but got ahead of what it should show, "running fast" would be more appropriate, or "gaining...", specifying how much it gains. My grandparents fully mechanical clocks were sometimes described as "running fast"

Answer (score 20):

The idiomatic expression is **that clock is off**.

The use of "off" in this way matches the 3rd adjective definition on this [Merriam-Webster page](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/off):

> not corresponding to fact : INCORRECT

Other expressions that use "off" in this manner are "my calculations are off" (differing from the expected value) or "my balance is off" (not centered).

This could cause some ambiguity between the clock being unpowered vs. incorrect.  But since clocks are almost always intended to be powered, the meaning is will usually be clear from context.  (A clock that is unpowered or broken is usually called "stopped": *Your clock has stopped*.)

Here are some web pages demonstrating this usage:

- [CoCalc says your clock is off](https://doc.cocalc.com/howto/clock-is-off.html)
- [Clock is off by 1 hour???](https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/130028-clock-off-1-hour.html)
- [...the clock is off by 3 minutes...](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows10/comments/i8c5tc/any_reason_why_the_clock_is_off_by_3_minutes/)
- [Clock is off by one hour in new install](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/clock-is-off-by-one-hour-in-new-install-how-to-fix/40000)

Comment: All of those references are to computer internal clocks, in a context where the message is that computer clock is working but wrong, and is offset (off) by a certain amount of time (even the first one, if you follow the link).

Comment: @RandyOrrison That's just because people don't have other clocks any more. Off doesn't strictly mean offset, it can also just mean not where/when it's supposed to be (e.g. "off schedule").

Comment: This answer surprises me.  It's certainly not idiomatic where I live.  In fact, if somebody pointed to a clock on the wall and said _"that clock is off"_, I'd interpret that to mean that it's an electric clock that has been switched off, in other words, it's not running at all.  In what region is _"the clock is off"_ idiomatic, meaning _"showing the incorrect time"_?

Comment: @Dawood ibn Kareem I'm from Pennsylvania in the US.  I grew up in the 1970s, so the expression was not limited to computer or even digital clocks.  The expression wasn't limited to clocks.  Pretty much any measuring device could be said to be "off."  For example, you could say your "My speedometer is off" if it wasn't measuring correctly.  Or "That thermometer is off" if it was reading high or low.  We would say an analog clock was "stopped" if it wasn't moving, or "Your clock is out" if a digital clock display was blank.

Comment: Interesting!  I've never been to Pennsylvania.  Oddly, I would understand _"your clock is out"_ to mean _"your clock is showing the wrong time"_, not _"the display is blank"_.  Thank you for replying.

Comment: @RandyOrrison it is used for non-computer clocks - but I've only ever come across it in the sense of "off by [some margin]".

Comment: @SyntaxJunkie - yes, and a common computer software problem is the 'off-by-one error' due to coding errors such as using "is less than or equal to" where "is less than" should have been used in a comparison, or not realising that a sequence starts at zero rather than one (as with array indices in many languages). There is also the good old 'fence-post error'.

Comment: I am from a completely different part of the US, and can confirm that "that clock is off" meaning that it is incorrect by some amount, not that it is unpowered, or limited to computer based usage, is certainly idiomatic. Perhaps this is idiomatic to the US only.

Comment: @GlenYates I find “the clock is off by [some amount]” to be perfectly idiomatic and natural. But like Dawood, I would understand “the clock is off” on its own as parallel to “the radio is off”, meaning that it’s _turned off_. Obviously, if it’s a grandfather clock, that doesn’t apply, so it would be the ‘off by’ sense by default there, but with a digital clock, the ‘turned off’ sense would prevail.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Are you a native English speaker? Are you from the US?

Comment: @GlenYates Yes (bilingually), though I didn't grow up in an English-speaking country. My English is an admixture of British and American English, with the latter being probably just a bit more innate and native. Thus far, opinion seems divided between you, Syntax Junkie and user3067860 on one side, and me, Dawood (+4 upvoters), Chris (+1 upvoter) and Randy (I think), which indicates that it is a dialectal difference.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet And that is my point, that this is probably an American English idiom.

Comment: California girl chiming in here that this is definitely NOT idiomatic to me. The only two ways "the clock is off" makes sense to me are (1) if the clock has been powered off, or (2) if it's the start of "the clock is off by [such-and-such amount]".

Comment: Brit here - "That clock is off" would imply to me that it is unpowered (a weird thing to say, given a clock with hands might be mechanical). I guess if said with a US accent, or other reference, we might be able to infer the clock is showing incorrect time, but it's not a natural expression. If you said "it's off by 3 minutes", we'd understand what you meant, but would normally say "it's slow (or fast) by 3 minutes" ourselves.

Comment: A *dead* clock is one w/o any potential energy and is correct twice a day. A clock that is *off*, but otherwise accurate, will never show the correct time. If you young whippersnappers could try not to think of everything in terms of computers or digital displays, especially clocks, that'd be great ;) Midwesterner, +1.

Comment: By its definition it is by definition *not* an idiom, but with these comments I'm not so sure anymore.... California and Texas count as much as anyone on the other side of the pond does. If I had a nickle for every time I read *this must be a [insert country here] thing*, well I'd have like 95 cents. Lemme know when dialect tags are required here.

Answer (score 1):

There are excellent answers already, and it's worth adding that "What's the time?" or "Have you got the time?" is a slightly old fashioned way of asking "What time is it?". So the woman's "That's not the time" seems to be a natural corollary. I wonder how old the woman was...

Comment: I think it would be a little more common to say "That's not the *correct* time".

Comment: I don’t think *What’s the time?* is old-fashioned at all, at least in my experience (mostly UK-based).

Comment: “Have you got the time?” isn’t (directly) asking the same thing as “What time is it?”. The latter is a straightforward request to be told the current time; the former asks someone _whether they have a watch available_. It’s only implied that the purpose of that question is to be informed of the current time (though of course that is the question most people would actually answer).

Comment: When I was younger, if someone said 'Have you got the time?' a jocular response might be 'Yes, if you've got the money'.

Comment: Perhaps why that fell out of favor @MichaelHarvey :)

Comment: @G.Ann-SonarSourceTeam - another witty reply (before the days of smokers mostly using cigarette lighters) was if someone said 'Have you got a match?'. You reply 'Yes. Your face, my ass'.

Answer (score 0):

In English, there is a humorous way to express how a clock's time is incorrect, though it only applies if the clock is stopped. In such a case, we can say the clock is right twice each day!

If you don't understand, it is because the "stopped time" on a 12-hour clock matches reality once in the AM and once in the PM. For cultural learning, it is useful to remember that this concept is more typically used to highlight how sometimes people are right about things but not because they are a trustworthy source. For example, person A might say, "I bet that guy is a very knowledgeable sports fan. He predicted that Argentina would win the FIFA World Cup in 2022!" Person B might retort, "Yeah, but even a stopped clock is right twice a day." In the USA, practically everybody has heard this idiom.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds a bit like an internal conversation (with the clock).

A bit like a carpenter muttering “huh, that’s no good” rather than saying “this chisel is not sharp”.

“That clock is wrong” is what you would tell someone, if you thought it was any of your business and/or that the person you were talking to might care.

Comment: Hi Colin! Please read through the other answers before answering. Your option has already been mentioned.